# Injecting process

Tags: code-injection, malware

I have a program. When it is runned, it runs another legal proces (f.e. icq.exe, atp.) and then it inject itself's code into it (f.e. icq.exe). Icq.exe will not be runned, it only appears in taskmaanager. digitally signed and everything what ICQ.exe has.
BUt when I look in strings in memory, there is nothing from icq.exe but from prevously used program who runs this.

How is it possible? I was lookping for something and couldnt found anything. It doesnt run only icq. but it radomly pick up some program on harddrive.

Comment: what do u mean by injecting itself (injecting a dll) ??

Comment: nono, this malware program inject itself in this .exe file (ICQ). When I check strings, they are in ICQ file the same like in malware file